# Looping through columns to conduct data manipulations in a data frame

Tags: pandas, loops

One struggle I have with using Python Pandas is to repeat the same coding scheme for a large number of columns. For example, below is trying to create a new column age_b in a data frame called data. How do I easily loop through a long (100s or even 1000s) of numeric columns, do the exact same thing, with the newly created column names being the existing name with a prefix or suffix string such as "_b".

```
labels = [1,2,3,4,5]
data['age_b'] = pd.cut(data['age'],bins=5, labels=labels)
```

In general, I have many simply data frame column manipulations or calculations, and it's easy to write the code. However, so often I want to repeat the same process for dozens of columns, that's when I get bogged down, because most functions or manipulations would work for one column, but not easily repeatable to many columns. It would be nice if someone can suggest a looping code "structure". Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but let's say my data frame has age column ranging between 18 to 99 in values, along with many other numeric columns. The idea is I want to cut all numeric columns into 5 identical bins. The original numeric columns may be: var1, var2, var3, ....The newly created ones will be called var1_cat, var2_cat, var3_cat...... I am just wondering how I can loop through these two lists of columns to do the same coding as above. Hope this helps clarifying the question a bit.